# create a custom .iso of loki

Tags: release-loki, settings, iso

I have set up a virtual machine, and I have included a lot customizations. 
Now I decided to transfer the virtual machine in the place of a windows pc. I know that I can cp -a all, and restore it. But it would be interesting to create a custom iso of loki, like remastersys did for ubuntu. Is it possible somehow?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had to install Loki multiple times, but I used the official iso file, and created a bash script, that set up my system for my needs. I suggest You do the same, just list everything You've done earlier as bash commands and run the script after installation.

Comment: Good idea! I do this whatever distro I'm using, to install all the software I need. I don't know whether it would be possible to use it for customization though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time, you can always try it with the Ubuntu version of Respin/Remastersys (http://www.remastersys.org/). But there is no guarantee that it will work with elementary OS as well. If you decide to do so, you might even want to answer your question based on the experience you have.

However, if you only need one pc with your custom install, the way you suggested ("`cp -a`") should be the fastest and safest way to do it.